# EXCEL-VBA: Save userform controls as picture

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to develop a macro that updates/generates the footer/header of excel files for my company. 
The first version of this macro uses a sheet to store the required info (pics, text) and it works. 
I want to go one step further and eliminate the sheet where the macro info is stored by moving all required info in userforms.

So, I have UserForm1 which has the company logo picture. This is saved using `SavePicture UserForm1.Logo.Picture, "D:\Logo.png"` where Logo is an Image control.

In UserForm2, I have a Frame control (named FooterText), populated with labels which need to be updated prior to saving the entire frame as png (or whatever picture format). Needless to say that `SavePicture UserForm2.FooterText.Picture, "D:\Footer.png"` does not work. The text for the footer exceeds the limit set by office and as such, can only be added as a picture.

Are there any options for me at this point? Is there a simple solution for exporting userform controls as picture? I don't want to complicate things by adding new references since it will be required by all company users.